# Joomla. Parent menu which won't redirect

Tags: html, joomla, menu, hyperlink, menuitem

I want to create menu in Joomla that won't redirect but will show only submenu.

```
Menu:
->Home
->Docs
-->Link1
-->Link2
```

It should looks like that. When im at home link and when i click on Docs, I still stay at home but i can see Link1 and Link2

How to do that?

Best Regards,
Sheryf

Answer (score 0):

I think you need non-clickable menu, where user can not click on it but can access the sub-menu. So you can use **"Text-separator"** menu type from menu manager. You can refer this image

[image]

Also see this link for further help:

[Help25:Menus Menu Item Text Separator](http://docs.joomla.org/Help25:Menus_Menu_Item_Text_Separator)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Sheryf You need to enable the option in you module to show sub-menu in menu module.